# Vue js how to chek multiple v-if condition from one function return in same page

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

This is my code

```html
<button v-if="$can('permission-a')">Add User</button>
<button v-if="$can('permission-b')">Add Employee</button>
```

And this is my $can method

```js
data() {
  return {
    returnAccess: false
  };
},

methods: {
  $can(permissionName) {
    let route = window.routes.permission;
    let returnAccess;

    axios
      .get(route + `/${permissionName}`)
      .then(resounse => {
        if (resounse.data == 101) {
          this.returnAccess = true;
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.returnAccess = false;
      });

    return this.returnAccess;
  },
}
```

$can method return false for add user button and return true for add employee button. But add user button also showing because of true return for add employee button.

How can i solve this issue. Any one can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need to return a value

create a permissions object:

```
data() {
return {
  permissions: {}
};
```

and a method like:

```
methods: {
$can(permissionName) {
  let route = window.routes.permission;
  let returnAccess;
  axios
    .get(route + `/${permissionName}`)
    .then(resounse => {
      if (resounse.data == 101) {
        this.permissions.permissionName = true;
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.permissions.permissionName = false;
    });
},
}
```

now foreach this in your created()

```
created() {
let permissionNames = ['a', 'b'];
        permissionNames.forEach(function(permissionName) {
            this.$can(permissionName) {
        });
}
```

this way you create a object with keys as the permisson.
now in html you can simple do:

```
<button v-if="permission.somePermission">Add User</button>
<button v-if="permission.somePermission">Add Employee</button>
```

NOTE: not tested, but hope you get the idea

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. How will i get this permission object globally in all vue components. Now am using $can method in a global file inside resources/js/mixins/ folder. But this component's create method is calling lot of times repeatedly when the page load. Can u help me for that. Am using laravel 5.8

Comment: you should take a look at vuex for global variables. If you need any help, let me know. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

Comment: Glad I could help